# I have used TableViewCell in Different TableView. So how do I fetch TableViewCell's selected button's value to TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I have created .h, .m and .xib files named SweepStakeTableViewCell respectively and in my xib File I have replace the View to Cell which looks like this.

[image]

Now, I have written All the code to select buttons. I have successfully integrate this cell into the Table that has different .h, .m and .Xib files named SweepViewController. and output of that XIB will show participans and option buttons like this.
[image]

**Now Coming to the main point I want to pass the selected button's value to SweepViewController's and logic of selecting button is sitting in SweepStakeTableViewCell.**

Please Help me with this. If You can not get my question clearly plz do I ask me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, there are two approaches:

1) Store a reference to the SweepViewController in the SweepStakeTableViewCells. Do this by adding a property (i.e. instance variable and a public setter) to the subclass and setting it when you create cells in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

2) Use the notification system provided by Apple. Your viewController will need to register an an observer. Then your cells can post notifications and they will be picked up by the viewController. Check the docs for NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate for the SweepStakeTableViewCell and assign the SweepViewController to it.

```
@protocol SweepStakeTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)sweepTableViewCell:(SweepStakeTableViewCell *)cell buttonSelected:(UIButton *)button;
@end
```

Assign the view controller (in this case self) to the SweepStakeTableViewCell delegate method when creating the cell in the table view delegate method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[SweepStakeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    .
    .
    .
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

For the SweepStakeTableViewCell

```
@interface SweepStakeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
.
.
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SweepStakeTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
.
@end

@implementation SweepStakeTableViewCell
.
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sweepTableViewCell:buttonSelected:)])
    {
        [delegate sweepTableViewCell:self buttonSelected:sender];
    }
}
.
@end
```

When the button is selected in the table view cell, it will call the delegate method which in this case the view controller with the cell and selected button that you can retrieve the values.